# copying an array to the same array

Tags: java, arrays

So I have a array with elements [10] that I add from the top of the array so something like this

["","","","","",5,4,3,2,1]

and when I remove a element I wanted to shift up ones below it to take its place

["","","","","",5,3,2,1]

```
public void moveUP(int location, int Arraysize) {

    System.arraycopy(vehicle, 0, vehicle, 0, location + 1);
}
```

I tried using the array copy but when I check the debugger the elements are remaining the same.

edit: forgot to mention that location was the element I planned on removing.

Comment: You could write a `for` loop, that will start at `location` and moves "to the left" to shift the elements "to the right". And on index `0` it inserts an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct function should look like this:

```
public void moveUP(int location, int arraysize){
    System.arraycopy(vehicle, 0, vehicle, 1, location-1);
    vehicle[0] = "";
}
```

This moves every element from 0 to location-1 one place to end, so its after the copy on position 1....location (so the element on position is deleted)

Comment: You might want to add that OP should use just `location` (instead of `location-1`) if `location` is zero based. But good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible with one call of `System.arraycopy`. You can shift all elements of an array to the left or to the right with `arraycopy` (assuming you have enough space) but either way there will be old leftover elements which have only been copied and not set to 0/null. Example:

```
int[] test = new int[] {0,0,7,7};
System.arraycopy(test, 2, test, 1, 2); // this will shift all elements 
                                       // starting at position 2 to position 1
// but test now looks like this = [0,7,7,7]
```

So the last `7` is still there. A solution for this could look something like this:

```
int[] newArr = new int[oldArr.length];
System.arraycopy(oldArr, 0, newArr, 0, posToBeDeleted);
System.arraycopy(oldArr, posToBeDeleted+1, newArr, posToBeDeleted, elemsRemaining);
oldArr = newArr;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `destPos` argument is the fourth one, not fifth one. Your call should probably look like `System.arraycopy(vehicle, 0, vehicle, location, Arraysize)`, assuming you want to shift from 0 to `location`, and there are `Arraysize` elements in your array.